# Does Facebook downloads the video from the url, specified in `file_url` parameter when creating an advideo?

Tags: graphql, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to create an advideo using Facebook Marketing GraphQL API and I am wondering about two things:

1. Does FB saves the link to the video specified in `file_url` or downloads the video from that URL and saves it somewhere in Facebook storage.
2. If you specify the `source` parameter as encoded video, you don't need to specify the `file_url` parameter, right?

My questions are based on this doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/advideos#Creating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Every ad video is saved by, and served from the servers of, Facebook. You can easily test it yourself; create an ad video with `file_url` provided, then check the `source` property  (not to be confused with the property of same name when posting to the edge) of the newly-created video: it will point to a Facebook CDN address.
2. Yes, that's correct.